# Не работает фильтр array_filter php

Tags: php, массивы, фильтрация, перебор

Хочу от фильтровать массив, где есть значения "o" но что-то неправильно делаю, что надо изменить в коде? Чтоб массив отфильтровался и сохранял новые значения в новый массив? Вот код

```
$s=["zo", "vis", "oyi", "dre", "xoz"];
$zet="o";

foreach($s as $value){

   $z=filter_array($zet, $value);
    echo $z;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, правильно ли я вас понял.
Но вот:

```
    $s = ["zo", "vis", "oyi", "dre", "xoz"];

    $zet = "o";

    $filtered_array = array_filter($s, function($e) use ($zet) {
       return false !== strpos($e, $zet);
    });


    foreach ($filtered_array as $item) {
        echo $item . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$z=array_filter($s, function($v) use ($zet) {
           return $v == $zet;
       });
```

Тогда вам вернет массив в виде [место строки, которая совпала с поиском => строка, которую искали]

Например если $zet будет равно "zo" то:

```
foreach($z as $place => $str) {
    echo 'Место в массиве:' . $place . ', искомая строка: ' . $str; 
}
//Место в массиве:0, искомая строка: zo
```

Comment: Думаете есть смысл дублировать ответ для такого тривиального вопроса?)

Comment: @ВадимАлександру я не увидел ваш ответ))

Comment: Да правильно, а можно как-то более короче код сделать как в JS ? s =["zo", "vis", "oyi", "dre", "xoz"];

x=s.filter(arr=>arr.includes('o'));
console.log(x);

Comment: @Грустьжизни вот тут уже не подскажу ,извините)

Comment: Спасибо за ваши старания

Comment: @Грустьжизни если хотите короче, можно так `$f = array_filter($s, fn($e) => false !== strpos($e, $zet));` но только в php 7.4